# Why is this program crashing ? Did I wrongly allocate memory?

Tags: c++, inheritance

**Question**

Design a class Employee with name and employee number. Derive Manager, Scientist and Laborer classes. The manager class has extra attributes title and dues. The scientist class has extra attribute number of publications. The Laborer class has nothing extra. The classes have necessary functions for set and display the information.

**My solution**

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstring>
using namespace std;
class employee
{
protected:
    char *name;
    int number;
public:
    employee()
    {
        cout<<"enter employee name  \n";
        cin>>name;
        cout<<"enter employee number \n";
        cin>>number;        
    }
    void display()
    {
        cout<<"name \t"<<name<<endl;
        cout<<"number \t"<<number<<endl;
       // inside class function is a inline function
    }        
};
class manager: private employee 
{
    float due;
    char *title;
    public: 
    manager( )
    {
        cout<<"due\t "<<endl; 
        cin>>due;
        cout<<"title\t"<<endl;
        cin>>title;
        fflush(stdin);
    }

    void display()
    {
        employee::display();     //inside class function is a inline function
        cout<<"due\t"<<due<<endl;
        cout<<"title\t"<<title<<endl;
        //inside class function is a inline function
    }
};
class labour :private employee
{
public:

    void display()
    {    
        employee::display();      //inside class function is a inline function
    }
}; 
class  Scientist :private employee
{
    int number;
public:
    Scientist()
    {    
        cout<<"publication number "<<endl;
        cin>>Scientist::number;
    }

    void display()                  
    {
        employee::display();  
        cout<<" pub number "<<Scientist::number<<endl;
        fflush(stdin);
    }  //inside class function is a inline function

};

int  main()
{
    manager m;
    m.display();        
    Scientist s;
    s. display();
    labour l;
    l.display();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't use C strings - since this is supposed to be C++ then use `std::string`. Also don't call `fflush(stdin)` - it's non-portable at best, and UB at worst. Formatting the code properly would be a good idea too.

Comment: `fflush(stdin);` is undefined. Don't do it.

Comment: And constructors are not supposed to interact with the user in any way.

Comment: Debug your code and you'll find the answer by yourself.

Comment: @molbdnilo "no ctor-user interaction": Interesting. I have an idea why one might establish this rule, but Is there a consensus about it? Any sources/papers?

Comment: @PeterSchneider There's reusability, abstraction, the Single Responsibility Principle, Separation of Concerns, the "I did that once and regretted it"-rule, and many others. Take your pick. (Try to create an array or an `std::map` of the `employee` in the question and you'll see that it's really not a good idea.)

Comment: @molbdnilo I understand but I asked for references. Also, types used in arrays need a default ctor which is often not advisable or even possible, so that can hardly be an argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't allocate any memory for `title` or `name`, so you can't read into them from `std::cin`. Instead of using `char*` you should use `std::string` which will do all of the allocation for you:

```
std::string title;
std::string name;
```

Answer (score 0):

In the constructor of `empolyee` you read into an uninitialized `char*`. Therefore it does not point to a valid block of memory where you could store the entered name to. You could do

```
name = static_cast<char*>(malloc( 32 * sizeof(char) ));
```

to allocate memory such that name points to valid memory, but you always waste memory or do not have enough for the input. Also you have to free the memory in the destructor.

As Peter Schneider wrote in the comment of this answer, another option is to use arrays of a fixed size as a member, e.g.

```
char name[MAX_NAME_LENGTH];
```

with a e.g. preprocessor defined

```
#define MAX_NAME_LENGTH 64
```

at the top of your file. This way the copy constructor does his job. With pointers as members, you always have to write them yourself, otherwise, the original class instance and copied instance will have a member pointer pointing to the same memory. So if one the copied instance changes the name, the original instance will have a changed name, too.

The easiest solution would be to use a `std::string` instead of `char*`. It allocates memory on its own and you don't have to free anything and copying works fine, too.

Comment: If std::strings were not available I would just define an array `char name[MAX_NAME_LEN];`, obviating the need to explicitly free that.

Comment: Btw, copy and assignment also are simpler, i.e. implicit, with array members.

Comment: I added your suggestion to the answer. Thanks for that.